# Change Message-ID PHPMailer

Tags: php, smtp, gmail, phpmailer

Hello I am making a php based mailing application that will connect with a external smtp server and send emails. Now I have managed to match everything but the Message-ID's @domain-name and Sender domain name are not matching...

This is the result I am getting :
[Wrong Message ID Header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QEvhi.png)

and this is the result I should be getting (this email is sent from Mailwizz connected with the same SMTP server I am trying to connect with my application)

[Expected Message ID Header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8U347.png)

send.php file which I am using to connect with SMTP using PHPMailer

```
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require 'PHPMailer/Exception.php';
require 'PHPMailer/PHPMailer.php';
require 'PHPMailer/SMTP.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer;

$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->Host = 'smtp*****************';
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = 'notify@send.al***********';
$mail->Password = '**********';
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$mail->Port = 80;

$mail->SetFrom('jon@al***********','John Adams');
$mail->Sender = 'notify@send.al*********';
$mail->addAddress('*********@gmail.com');
$mail->Subject = 'Hello This is a TEST FROM SMTP';
$mail->isHTML(false);
$mail->Body = 'Hello let me know when its received';
$mail->addCustomHeader('X-Sender', 'notify@send.al**********');
$mail->XMailer=null;
$mail->MessageID = md5('HELLO'.(idate("U")-1000000000).uniqid()).'-'.$type.'-'.$id.'@send.al*********';
if(!$mail->send()){
    echo 'Error is '.$mail->ErrorInfo;
}
else{
    echo 'Message has been sent!';
}
?>
```

Comment: i am not talking about having the same message ID, i am just mentioning that the @domainname after the message is not the same as the sending domain

Comment: like if i send from mail@xyz.com then the message id should be <some-random-text@xyz.com> here in my error case, i am getting message ID as <some-random-text@abc.com> it should be <some-random-text@xyz.com>

Comment: sometimes your host provider have mail channels. this change your mailing system for somethings

Comment: Have to mention you don't have to worry about this, is just a server configuration from your hosting providers, mailingchannel help to servers provider to don't block their customers domains and protect to be on a blacklist of spamming emails.

Comment: Dont you all think that this is indeed by phpmailer itself, like see this snippet of code from phpmailer.php


        $DKIMquery = 'dns/txt'; //Query method
        $DKIMtime = time();
        //Always sign these headers without being asked
        //Recommended list from https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6376#section-5.4.1
        $autoSignHeaders = [
            'from',
            'to',
            'cc',
            'date',
            'subject',
            'reply-to',
            'message-id',
            'content-type',
            'mime-version',

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience, you do not need to use addCustomHeader if you want to set the MessageID.

Assuming that you want to set the Message ID to be [random]@send.alok, then please use the following:

```
$mail->MessageID = "<" . md5('HELLO'.(idate("U")-1000000000).uniqid()).'@send.alok>';
```

Hence, please the following will be ok:

```
<?php
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer; 
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception; 

require './Exception.php'; 
require './PHPMailer.php'; 
require './SMTP.php'; 



$user='smtp_xxxxxx_user';
$pass='smtp_password';
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);                              

try { 

    $mail->CharSet ="UTF-8";       
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 0;                      
    $mail->isSMTP();                             
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.xxxxx.com';        

    $mail->Username = $user;               
    $mail->Password = $pass;             


$mail->MessageID = "<" . md5('HELLO'.(idate("U")-1000000000).uniqid()).'@send.alok>';


  $mail->setFrom('jon@alxxxx.com', 'Jon Al');  
  $mail->addAddress('jon@gmail.com');  

$subject="test";
$message="test123";

    $mail->Port = 25;                             
    $mail->isHTML(true);                                  
    $mail->Subject = $subject;
    $mail->Body    = $message;
    $mail->send(); 
//    echo 'Success'; 
} catch (Exception $e) { 
//echo 'Failed'; 
}

?>
```

You may refer to the screen dump **below** for the result

[image: Email received]